# Pass data with express handlebars for simple node webapp

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, webpack

I am trying to use express handlebars to pass over data to my index.html page but it doesn't seem to be working. This is my express code:

**server.js code**:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const expressHandlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');

app.engine('html', expressHandlebars({ defaultLayout: 'main' }));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('/*', (request: any, response: any) => {
    response.render(path.resolve('dist/', 'index.html'), {
        testBars: 'TEST',
        layout: false
    });
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('started');
});
```

**index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test page</title>
</head>

<body>
 {{testBars}}
</body>

</html>
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
'use strict';

const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const NodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/app/server/server.ts',
    target: 'node',
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin([
            { from: './src/**/*.html', flatten: true }
        ])
    ],
    externals: [NodeExternals()],
    output: {
        filename: 'server.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }]
    }
};
```

When I run the server and serve the index page, it shows `{{testBars}}` on the page, not the string "TEST". I use webpack to build and bundle/copy everything (config above). My directory structure ends up being "dist/server.js" and "dist/index.html" after webpack runs.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Why won't it show "TEST" in index.html? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `index.html` is in your `dist` directory, your static route is going to match it **before** your `app.get('/*',` route is reached.

Don't keep your static files and templates in the same directory.

Comment: Thank you so much! The main problem was having the static files and templates in the same directory. I moved my index.html to a "dist/templates/" folder and it works now.